# React-Native error this.setState is not a function

Tags: react-native, setstate

I'm using below lib to implement a callback (onSuccess, onError) for every ApiRequest. But I have a problem when update state when event is trigged. I tried to remove all stuffs just keep the base logic. I don't know why it error.
Lib: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-simple-events

Below is my code

ApiRequest.js

```
import Events from 'react-native-simple-events';
export function login(email, password) {
       Events.trigger('LoginSuccess', 'response');
}
```

Login.js

```
import React, { Component, } from 'react'
import {
  View,
  Text,
} from 'react-native'
import Events from 'react-native-simple-events';

import * as request from '../../network/ApiRequest'
class LoginScreen extends Component {

  static propTypes = {}

  static defaultProps = {}

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      status: "new"
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    Events.on('LoginSuccess', 'myID', this.onLoginSuccess); 
    request.login("abc","def")

  }
    componentWillUnmount() {

      Events.rm('LoginSuccess', 'myID');

    }

  onLoginSuccess(data){ 
    this.setState({ //=>error here
       status : "done"
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>
          {this.state.status}
        </Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

let me know if you need more information

Comment: Did u check whether `this` is accessible inside `onLoginSuccess` function? Try to print `this` inside `onLoginSuccess` function. If this is not accessible then you need to bind `this` while u call `onLoginSuccess`

`Events.on('LoginSuccess', 'myID', this.onLoginSuccess.bind(this)); `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind this on the `onLoginSuccess` method:

```
Events.on('LoginSuccess', 'myID', this.onLoginSuccess.bind(this));
```